# AndroidJavaException cannot create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare in Unity

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

Here is my code. And I am getting error AndroidJavaException cannot create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare in Unity at activity.Call(runOnUiThread)

```
public static void showToast(string text)
        {
            if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
            {
                AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                AndroidJavaClass Toast = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
                AndroidJavaObject javaString = new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String", text);
                AndroidJavaObject context = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");
                AndroidJavaObject toast = Toast.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("makeText", context, javaString, Toast.GetStatic<int>("LENGTH_SHORT"));
                activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(()=> { toast.Call("show"); }));
            }
        }
```

if have solution Please help.What I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance

Comment: You have any solution to resolve this error.if have solution Please help.What I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that unity player runs in the thread the does not have a looper, this means anything that requires handler/looper must be run on UI thread, in your case

```
            activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(()=> 
        { 
            AndroidJavaClass Toast = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
            AndroidJavaObject javaString = new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String", text);
            AndroidJavaObject context = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");
            AndroidJavaObject toast = Toast.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("makeText", context, javaString, Toast.GetStatic<int>("LENGTH_SHORT"));
            toast.Call("show"); }
        ));
```

Or maybe just `makeText` part

Comment: Can I have a more information? I can't finde a unity player's thread and doesn't have a looper.

Answer (score 0):

UnityPlayer creates only  one activity for whole app. and it runs on a background Thread that does not have looper.
So anything that requires handler/looper must be run on UI thread.

```
public static void showToast(string text)
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaClass Toast = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
        AndroidJavaObject javaString = new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String", text);
        AndroidJavaObject context = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");
        activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(()=> { 
            AndroidJavaObject toast = Toast.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("makeText", context, javaString, Toast.GetStatic<int>("LENGTH_SHORT"));
            toast.Call("show"); }));
                }
            }
```